# MFC Application crash immediately after start

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I simply create a win32 project in visual studio 2012 on Windows8 x64. The project first is empty. I add a simple source.cpp file to the project. I paste these lines of code (which are sample of a book).

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <windows.h>


struct CSimpleApp : public CWinApp
{ 
BOOL InitInstance() { return TRUE; }
};
```

The program crash in winmain.cpp in AfxWinMain in line

```
if (!pThread->InitInstance())
```

The error is

Unhandled exception at 0x0F6AD5D2 (mfc110ud.dll) in Win32Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

how can I solve this error

Comment: The error says that a `NULL` pointer was accessed. Please edit your question to include a more complete example, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, when in the debugger, you should look up the function call stack to see your code, where the likely problem is.

Comment: All the code I wrote was the first section. The error raised in winmain.cpp that belongs to microsoft. I do know that pThread is NULL. but I don't know why the program call this file, and Why this pointer is NULL.

Comment: googling "afxwinmain pthread null" gives a few results eg http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/06/21/why-afxgetthread-returns-null-in-afxwinmain.aspx Do you have a

Comment: Did you create `CSimpleApp` global variable?

Comment: [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html)

Answer (score 3):

Today, I had an MFC testproject of mine crash similar weirdly with a call stack of:

```
    mfc100u.dll!AfxWinMain()  + 0x69 bytes  
>   my.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 547 + 0x24 bytes   C
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes
```

and an access violation of:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x69e97505 (mfc100u.dll) in my.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

I had a similar test project that worked just fine, so I diffed the linker settings, and lo' the corrupt project was missing the **`/SUBSYSTEM`** switch (GUI -> Properties -> Linker -> Subsystem: "").

Fixing this from the empty value in the settings to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` made the project run again.

Comment: thank you. Have a project that hadn't been built in a while. Even though it was simple console app it had Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). Changing Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you've created an empty project and just added these lines of code to a new cpp file.

If you want to use Afx support, or MFC, you need to state that when you create the project.
I suggest you let the IDE create a *non*-empty project, check that builds and runs, then start adding code to it.

`pthread` should be initialised by the framework for you - if you allow it to automatically generate the supoorting code for you. From memory, at very least it creates a global (arggg) variable called `theApp` of type `CWinApp`, which will initialise things it needs, like threads.

Go back through (the sample of) the book very carefully and follow all the instructions. If that doesn't work, get a better book. Or buy the whole book. Or work through the [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9es9d1k4.aspx) on the msdn.

Comment: Yep CWinApp, worked for me. It was also necessary not to leave m_pMainWnd NULL.